# Maven POM - build rpms on RHEL6 w/ backwards compatiblity?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, rpmbuild

Maven noob here. We have tens of repos with POMs that build rpms and recently moved our CI system to CentOS 6. As a result rpm builds are no longer backwards compatible with RHEL 5. Apparently I need to state within the spec or the maven POM:

```
<defineStatement>_source_filedigest_algorithm md5</defineStatement>
<defineStatement>_binary_filedigest_algorithm md5</defineStatement>
```

Can I add this to our parent POM somehow? Otherwise I need to script the addition of these lines to a slew of repositories and that gets ugly and error-prone quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Is that a property?  Is that a configuration item for a plugin?  If it's a property, you could define a active profile on each machine building it.  This would be appropriate if it changes based on the machine running the build.  The profile would be defined in the conf/settings.xml  of the maven installation, and defined as active if it should be applied to all builds.  However, not knowing where that value is meant to be sent, I can only guess right now.

Comment: It's a configuration item for the rpm plugin. Does that mean I'm screwed and need to modify each POM?

Comment: Perhaps not.  It looks like you can define, as part of a Profile, plugin configuration.  So, for the plugin in question, add the specific item for the plugin in the profile, then make sure the profile is listed as an active profile.  What I'm not so sure about is whether the plugin configuration in the pom itself will merge in with or overwrite the plugin configuration from the conf/settings.xml file.  But, I'd give that a try before going through all of the projects.